# Duplicate MAC on a WiFi network - problems?

Tags: wireless-networking, mac-address

I understand that duplicate MAC addresses can generally cause trouble in an ethernet network. For instance, it can confuse a switch about which physical port to use for sending packets, since that switch would typically keep some table with that info.

But what about wireless?

If there are two devices on a network connected via wireless, and they have the same MAC address, what specifically could go wrong, here?

As far as I know, with wireless each packet is visible to everyone listening, so both devices will see packets meant for the other, but so what? For IP traffic I imagine they'd ignore packets targeting the wrong IP address...

Can anyone come up with specific examples where things go haywire in this situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate MAC address on the same LAN possible?](http://serverfault.com/questions/462178/duplicate-mac-address-on-the-same-lan-possible)

Comment: @kbeflo: I don't think it's a dupe - that question is answered under the assumption of wired ethernet. This is about wireless, specifically because that question doesn't give the info I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well the first thing I can think of is that even if the wireless works the way you suggest (packets would simply be broadcast to all clients with the destination MAC), having multiple clients sending replies back to the device that sent the packets out would potentially causing all kinds of confusion.

Imagine device A sending out a packet to device B & C that both have the same MAC.  Then device B needs packet 1 to be sent again, but device C has already requested packet 2, 3, etc.

Comment: It's radio. Broadcast is how it works in general, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it's broadcast from the perspective of raw radio signals.  But, I'm not certain how WPA and other layers might manipulate things beyond just a simple MAC <-> MAC addressing.  I would assume once the destination MAC received the message it would also have to be using the correct negotiated keys and such in order to read the information.

Comment: WPA certainly negotiates different keys for each association, and I'm not sure if an AP would even allow duplicate associations in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I preempted my answer with the assumption that it would work broadcasting the way it was suggested in the question.  I figure there are other issues that might prevent it from working too.  That was just the first one that came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to dig up some information based on the other commentary here:

A good post: [http://www.wirelessforums.org/alt-internet-wireless/does-wpa-psk-encrypt-mac-addresses-25082.html#post129554](https://web.archive.org/web/20130412113932/http://www.wirelessforums.org/alt-internet-wireless/does-wpa-psk-encrypt-mac-addresses-25082.html)

Some tidbits:

- The MAC is transmitted in the clear, under WPA
- If both devices were to respond to a given packet, then the AP might see those as duplicates and drop one. This could result in spotty traffic to one or both devices.

  - However, if only one device responds (as I could imagine is the case, if this is IP traffic and the dest address is wrong), it seems like it could work. I don't know under what situations a device might respond to a packet that is not meant for it, though.